# SQLite Query - Need to get multiple values from multiple keys

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a database as follows.

```
security_id   ticker   company_name
----------------------------------------------
   100019     PANL     UNIVERSAL DISPLAY CORP
    10001     NAFC     NASH FINCH CO
   100030     PRVT     PRIVATE MEDIA GROUP INC
   100033     REFR     RESEARCH FRONTIER INC
```

I have a list of ticker symbols like [`GOOG`, `NAFC`, `AAPL`, `PRVT`] and I want to get a list of `security_id`'s that are associated with these ticker symbols I have in the list.

I'm new to SQL, so at first I thought of obtaining it one by one by iteration, this works but its really, so I was wondering if there is a SQL statement that can help me.

Comment: What database are you running this query against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server it would be something similar to this:

```
select security_id,ticker from <your table name>
where ticker in ('GOOG', 'NAFC', 'AAPL', 'PRVT')
```

The in takes a list of strings as parameters to compare against the ticker column.  This would just be used if you were executing the t-sql in SQL Server Management Studio.  If you were to break this out in to a stored procedure then you would have to pass the tickers as CSV and then create a function to split the csv in to a temp table to compare against.

Updated to include the ticker in return to know which security_id belongs to which ticker.

Comment: This is also valid for Sql lite.. IN opeartor supported in it.

Comment: I believe it's also valid for PL/SQL (Oracle).